# To display data in Gridview when click Search Button using asp.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview

Hi I was designing web application in that when I click Search button the data which is already stored should display as grid view. Now I have created grid view using asp.net and in View code created code for the grid view. I was don't have any errors but when I click search doesn't show any data. Below is the view code.

```
    Private Sub BindGridView()
    Dim filter As String = ""
    Dim table1 As DataTable = New DataTable("Details")
    table1.Columns.Add("ReferenceNo")
    table1.Columns.Add("Title")
    table1.Columns.Add("CounterParty")
    table1.Columns.Add("OwnerDepartment")
    table1.Columns.Add("Status")
    table1.Columns.Add("CreatedBy")
    table1.Columns.Add("CreatedOn")
    table1.Rows.Clear()
    Dim conSQL As New SqlConnection(conStrDRS)
    conSQL.Open()
     Dim cmdSQL As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT ReferenceNo, Title,     CounterParty, OwnerDepartment, Status, CreatedBy, CreatedOn          FROM        dbo.Registration")
    cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL
    Dim adptSQL As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
    Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()
    adptSQL.Fill(myDataSet)
    conSQL.Close()
    Dim set1 As DataSet = New DataSet("Details")
    set1.Tables.Add(table1)
    Dim dvDetails As DataView = table1.DefaultView
    gvDetails.DataSource = table1
    gvDetails.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Below is the code for the Search button

```
  Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles        btnSearch.Click
     BindGridView()
End Sub
```

can anyone help me to fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are not assigning the returned data to the grid.
No need to create a table. Returned data set contains the table for you.

Call this on `Page_Load`

```
Private Sub BindGridView()
    Dim filter As String = ""
    Dim conSQL As New SqlConnection(conStrDRS)
    conSQL.Open()
     Dim cmdSQL As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT ReferenceNo, Title,     CounterParty, OwnerDepartment, Status, CreatedBy, CreatedOn          FROM        dbo.Registration")
    cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL
    Dim adptSQL As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
    Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()
    adptSQL.Fill(myDataSet)
    conSQL.Close()
    gvDetails.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0]
    gvDetails.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Call this for Search

```
Private Sub BindGridView(ByVal searchTerm As String)
        Dim filter As String = searchTerm
        Dim conSQL As New SqlConnection(conStrDRS)
        conSQL.Open()
         Dim cmdSQL As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT ReferenceNo, Title,     CounterParty, OwnerDepartment, Status, CreatedBy, CreatedOn          FROM        dbo.Registration WHERE ReferenceNo =" + searchTerm)//Add any term you want
        cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL
        Dim adptSQL As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
        Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()
        adptSQL.Fill(myDataSet)
        conSQL.Close()
        gvDetails.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0]
        gvDetails.DataBind()
    End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles        btnSearch.Click
     BindGridView(txtSearchTerm.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: hi @Irshad thanks for your reply now I will try that and what about the submit click button code is it correct??

Comment: It's fine I think. but you're not passing a search parameter through the click button.

Comment: Thanks its working but not when I click Search button it automatically display. Can you help me to pass parameters. Thanks

Comment: How you are entering the search term? Is it a text box? Are you calling this method on `Page_Load`?

Comment: Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As           System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
                                           BindGridView()
        End If
    End Sub
Is it Correct??

Comment: Got error System.NullReferenceException: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: Can you please tell how to filter the fields from data. for eg: if I select name as avi then it should display only avi files.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are filling `myDataSet` but binding the `gridview` with a new `DataTable` which will be empty so you need to bind it with `myDataSet`.

```
gvDetails.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0];
gvDetails.DataBind()
```

> You don't need to call `Open` and `Close` methods of `SqlConnection`
>   when using `SqlDataAdapter`.

You are creating extra `DataSet, DataTable and DataView` because you are not using these anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply can you help me to pass parameters for search Button.

Comment: Pass some id to `BindGridView` function.Then add paramter in SQl Query

Comment: Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load If Not IsPostBack Then BindGridView() End If End Sub 
Is it Correct??